# Adding a logo image to a chart using Microsoft Chart Control

Tags: c#, image, microsoft-chart-controls

I have a chart that is built using Microsoft Chart Controls and would like to add our company's logo to the corner. Is this possible to do with MCC?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add an image, use ImageAnnotation.

```
 ImageAnnotation logo = new ImageAnnotation();
 logo.X = 75;
 logo.Y = 60; 
 logo.Image = "imagePath";
 chart.Annotations.Add(logo);
```

Answer (score 2):

Is there any reason you don't want to simply put a PictureBox control near the corner of the chart?  That seems like that simplest solution to me.

Comment: It looks like PictureBox is used for forms. The chart images are generated dynamically on a server and sent out embedded in an email.

Comment: Ah I misunderstood, I was suggesting that you just put the picture control above the chart control on the form but that wouldn't show up on the image created from the control.